# electron-builder nsis run other executable during install

Tags: electron, nsis, electron-builder

I'm trying to run a different executable during install of my app but I cannot find the right path to do it. The program is added with the following `electron-builder` config:

```
extraFiles:
    -   from: tools/tapinstall/${arch}/
        to: resources/tapinstall/
        filter:
            - "**/*"
```

After installing my app I can see the files in the `resources/tapinstall/` folder so it's being ported. Now, in my `nsis` `installer.nsh` I added an `ExecWait` directive to run an `exe` from that directory but it fails.

As a desperate measure I figured that prefixing everything with `$INSTDIR` was not the right move, maybe the path is not `$INSTDIR` and something else and I found 3 possible candidates:

- `$INSTDIR`
- `$APPDATA`
- `$BUILD_RESOURCES_DIR`

I added this simple code to see which file gets created so I can figure out the right macro to use:

```
!macro customHeader
    RequestExecutionLevel admin
!macroend

!macro customInstall
    !system "echo 'as' > $INSTDIR/customInstall"
    !system "echo 'bs' > $APPDATA/customInstall"
    !system "echo 'cs' > $BUILD_RESOURCES_DIR/customInstall"

    ${ifNot} ${isUpdated}
        !system "echo 'a' > $INSTDIR/customInstall"
            !system "echo 'b' > $APPDATA/customInstall"
            !system "echo 'c' > $BUILD_RESOURCES_DIR/customInstall"
    ${endIf}
!macroend
```

I then did a full search on my computer for a file called `customInstall`...nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!system` (and all other `!` instructions) are executed at compile-time inside makensis.exe. You cannot access variables/constants at compile time, only defines and environment variables.

```
!define foo "Hello"
!warning "${NSISDIR} & $%Temp% & ${foo}"

Var Bar
Section
StrCpy $Bar "World"
MessageBox mb_ok "$InstDir & $Bar"
SectionEnd
```